# Authentication on Android Apps?

Tags: android, authentication

I have been building an application on android and wanted to do some user authentication using twitter oAuth. But is there any service by google which will allow user authentication easily? Could you please let me know if any other services exist for android ?

Regards,
Lalith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but I believe you can use openid authentication which accepts google login too. Details about openid with google is here:
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html

Comment: I went ahead with twitter OAuth.. it worked pretty well with signpost.